# Flux through surface

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, polar-coordinates

Can someone help/correct me in my thinking when working calculating the flux through a surface. Given is the following example:

When a vector field is described by:
$$
\vec{E} = xz\,\hat{\imath} - yz\,\hat{\jmath} + (x^2 + y^2)\,\hat{k}$$

And a circular disk through which we want to calculate the flux is described by:
$$
D \rightarrow\; z=0,\, x^2+y^2 \leq a^2
$$

I am aware that in order to calculate the flux through the surface we need a vector perpendicular to the surface of the disk to evaluate the integral. Since $z=0$, a unit normal vector is given by
$\hat{n} = 0\,\hat{\imath} + 0\,\hat{\jmath} + 1\,\hat{k}$ this could be used. Right?

We are taught that another way to determine a vector perpendicular to the surface $D$ is by parametrizing the surface $D$, as below for example, and then determining $\frac{\partial r}{\partial \rho} \times \frac{\partial r}{\partial \theta}$.
$$
D\rightarrow\; 
r(\rho, \theta) 
= \rho \cos(\theta)\,\hat{\imath} + \rho\sin(\theta)\,\hat{\jmath} + 0\,\hat{k}
$$
with $\rho \in [0, a] \land \theta \in [0, 2\pi]$.

Is it correct that the flux is then given by (question mark indicating I'm not sure about my understanding, and I might have gone wrong somewhere way earlier):
$$
\iint_D \vec{B} \cdot d \vec{S} \;\overset{?}{=}\, \iint_D \vec{B}(\vec{r}(\rho, \theta)) \cdot 
\biggl( \frac{\partial r}{\partial \rho} \times \frac{\partial r}{\partial \theta} \biggr) \, dA
$$

The length of this normal vector does matter right. So how has this been taken into account for in the integral with the cross product? Is it because you substitute the parameterization of the surface into the vector field?

Comment: Seems correct to me. Anyway the perpendicular vector $\hat{n}$ you say is fine to calculate the flux. 

You can think that the field $\vec{E}$ has three componentes, in the directions $\hat{i}$,$\hat{j}$ and $\hat{k}$. When we think about the flux of a field trough a surfaces, we want the "part" of the flux that crosses the surface. Here as the surface is in the $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ plane then we have that these components of the flux are tangent to the surface, so the only component that crosses the surface is the one in the $\hat{k}$ direction.

Comment: Yes. You are mostly correct. Note that the cross product in the last equation is still  proportional to $\rho$, so you need to divide by it. And you should probably write $dA$ in terms of $\rho$ and $\theta$.

Comment: @Andrei That's what I was thinking too, but in the exercises we are given they don't seem to normalize the crossproduct by dividing by its length. That confuses me.

Comment: *Notation:* `\imath` produces an $i$ without the dot so that the hat is easier to read: $\hat{\imath}$ and similarly for $\hat{\jmath}$. Also `\,` gives a small bit horizontal of horizontal whitespace which can make certain expressions easier to read. See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing) for more.

Comment: @BrianBritosSimmari Ah clear, but the length of this normal vector does matter right. So how has this been taken into account in the integral with the cross product? Is it because you substitute the parameterization of the surface into the vector field?

Comment: Note that $dS=\biggl| \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \rho} \times \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \theta} \biggr|dr d\theta$, $\vec{n}=\frac{\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \rho} \times \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \theta}}{\biggl| \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \rho} \times \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \theta} \biggr|}$, and therefore $d\vec{S}=\vec{n}dS=\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \rho} \times \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \theta} dr d\theta$